# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'line_items' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: node.js, postman, stripes

[image]I'm not getting any response from postman due to this error. I tried to add app.use(express.json()); in index.js but still not working. Any idea on how to solve this?

```js
const stripeAPI = require('../stripe');

async function createCheckoutsession(res, req) {
  const domainUrl = process.env.WEB_APP_URL;
  const { line_items, customer_email } = req.body;
  if (!line_items || !customer_email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'missing required session paramaters' });
  }
  
  let session;
  
  try {
    session = await stripeAPI.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      mode: 'payment',
      line_items,
      customer_email,
      success_url: `${domainUrl}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${domainUrl}/canceled`,
      shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ['GB', 'US'] }
    });
    res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id, });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'an error occurred, unable to create session' });
  }
}

module.exports = createCheckoutsession;
```

(index.js)

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });

const createCheckoutSession = require('./api//checkout');

const app = express();

const port = 8080;

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({origin: true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('HELLO WORLD!'));

app.post('/create-checkout-session', createCheckoutSession);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port', port));

(stripe.js)

const stripeAPI = require('stripe')(process.env.SECRET_KEY);

module.exports = stripeAPI;`enter code here`

Comment: {
    "line_items": 
    [ 
        {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price_data": {
        "currency": "usd",
         "unit_amount": 2800,
        "product_data": {
            "name": "Cumulus",
            "description": "Light as air",
            "images": [
                    "https://i.ibb.co/NtpJ0XQ/cumulus-olive.png"
                ]
        }
        }

      }

    ],

    "customer_email": "hellothere@gmail.com"
}

Comment: Hi Phil, I've uploaded the screenshot from postman

Comment: Ok, everything looks fine there. Can you show where you add `app.use(express.json())` and where you bind `createCheckoutsession` to the `/create-checkout-session` path? Note that your JSON middleware should be registered **before** `app.post("/create-checkout-session", createCheckoutsession)` (or however you've set up that handler)

Comment: app.use(express.json()) is in index.js, I've updated  it here so that you can see.. it is stated before app.post("/create-checkout-session"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Express server?

Your route handler is using wrong parameters:

```
// Wrong
async function createCheckoutsession(res, req) {
}

// Correct 
async function createCheckoutsession(req, res) {
}
```

Comment: iKoala, thank you for that.. i didn't notice it right away.... i'm getting 'an error occurred, unable to create session'  from postman, I suppose to get a sessionID as a postman response

Comment: I think it's another error from Stripe API, which is different from the error you stated in your question title.

Comment: Well spotted! 

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlEncoded({extended:false}))
```

Comment: body-parser is deprecated. Use [express.urlencoded()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) instead

Comment: Also, looks like OP is posting JSON

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried app.use(bodyParser.urlEncoded({extended:false})) and  express.urlencoded() both didn't work.

Comment: You have to download body-parser through npm then import it to your project